# Image BitDepth conversions on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, image-processing

I need to convert a 32 bpp image to 24, 16 bitdepths. Mine is a cocoa app in OS X. Which is the best way to do this? I have the raw image data (RGBA) in NSData. Are there any frameworks/APIs or libraries that can be used in OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a bit clearer about what you have and what you want. For example, what's the difference between 32bpp and 24bpp for your purposes?

In any case, the [vImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_conversion/index.html) routines are probably what you want, since you're starting from raw data. For example, `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toARGB1555()` is one way to convert a 32bpp image to 16bpp. `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toRGB565()` is a different way, although it ignores the alpha component.

`vImageConvert_ARGB8888toRGB888()` converts from 32bpp to 24bpp by simply dropping the alpha channel.

Etc.

Comment: Sorry for that. My intension is to reduce data size.

Comment: See how far you can get with vImageConvert_RGBA8888toRGB565_dithered with dithering turned on.